# Spring MVC and Pdf

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, itext

I am trying to implement [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-pdf-file-via-abstractpdfview/), but eclipse shows me the error that can not find com.lowagie namespace. I don't use maven. I have added iText.jar to Buildpath, but it does'n help.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try doing a Clean and Rebuild of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that they have changed their package names since version 2.1.7 (which is used in the example you have read). Where did you downloaded the iText.jar? From [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/iText/)? When you take a look into your jar could you verify that the package names are equal to com.lowagie?

Also when you don't use maven I would suggest to download the jar from the [maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse) so you can be sure that you have the right jar, means the jar used in your example.

Comment: If you leave 2.1.7 to go to 5 you will want to take note of the change in licensing.

Comment: Of course you can use iText 5 in combination with Spring MVC framework. But then it is not as simple as copy paste the example's code. At least you have to modify the iText related parts so that it uses the new version.